# Validating a jQuery Mobile Form

Tags: jquery

Is there a "best practice" for adding validation to jQuery Mobile forms? Since the Document Load function of jQuery doesn't fire, I don't understand where I can put client-side validation.

The documentation didn't help and I have done several tutorials and even bought a jQuery Mobile book, but none addresses validation.

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually recommend using a JQuery validation plug-in like the one at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation.  I used it in my JQuery Mobile app and it works just the same as if you were doing it on the web.