# Prevent default action occurring? (JQueryMobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have just implemented input field validations e.g. "Please enter your name" if an input field is left empty.

I done this through JQuery mobile, however the issue I am not having is that when the user submits (registerUser(); ) the form the validations do not occur (if left empty) in time and instead the data is submitted into the database.

How can I prevent the page from loading and parsing the data into the database if there are empty fields?

HTML -

```
<form id="form1">
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtusername" data-theme="d">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtusername" name="txtusername" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtfirstname" data-theme="d">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtfirstname" name="txtfirstname" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtlastname" data-theme="d">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtlastname" name="txtlastname" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtemail" data-theme="d">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="txtemail" name="txtemail" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Enter Email"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtpassword" data-theme="d">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="passwordconfirm" data-theme="d">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="passwordconfirm" name="passwordconfirm" data-theme="d" placeholder="Confirm password"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register User" onclick="return registerUser(); return false;">
```

JavaScript File (JQuery Mobile) -

```
 $('#form1').validate({
                         rules: {
                            txtusername: {
                                 required: true
                             },
                             txtfirstname: {
                                 required: true
                             },
                             txtlastname: {
                                 required: true
                             },
                             txtemail: {
                                 required: true
                                     },
                             txtpassword: {
                                   required: true
                                          },
                            passwordconfirm: {
                                   required: true
                                   }
                         },
                         messages: {
                             txtusername: {
                                 required: "Please enter your Username."
                             },
                             txtfirstname: {
                                 required: "Please enter your First Name."
                             },
                             txtlastname: {
                                 required: "Please enter your Last Name."
                             },
                             txtemail: {
                                     required: "Please enter your Email."
                                          },
                             txtpassword: {
                                    required: "Please enter your Password."
                                },
                             passwordconfirm: {
                                  required: "Please enter your password again."
                                 }
                         },
                         errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                             error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
                         },
                         submitHandler: function (form) {
                             $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#success', {
                                 reload: false
                             });
                             return false;
                         }
                     });
```

userRegister Function

```
 function registerUser() {
       var Username = document.getElementById("txtusername").value;
       var Firstname = document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value;
       var Lastname = document.getElementById("txtlastname").value;
       var Email = document.getElementById("txtemail").value;
       var Password = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
       var Confirmpass = document.getElementById("passwordconfirm").value;

         db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2*1024*1024);
         db.transaction(function(tx) {
          NewUser(tx, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Confirmpass);
          }, errorRegistration, successRegistration);
          }

          function NewUser(tx, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Confirmpass) {
          var _Query = ("INSERT INTO SoccerEarth(UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, CPass) values ('"+ Username +"','"+ Firstname +"','"+ Lastname +"','"+ Email +"', '"+ Password +"', '"+ Confirmpass +"')");
           alert(_Query);
           tx.executeSql(_Query);
           }
           function errorRegistration(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert(error, null, "Got an error mate", "cool");
            }
           function successRegistration() {
           navigator.notification.alert("User data has been registered", null, "Information", "ok");
             $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page4" );
         }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery mobile: how to validate the form and show error message on page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031415/jquery-mobile-how-to-validate-the-form-and-show-error-message-on-page)

Comment: Doesn't solve my issue though...

Comment: here some working examples: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785949/validating-a-jquery-mobile-form, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073317/jquery-mobile-form-validation-with-php-failing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820768/html-with-javascript-form-validation-and-jquery-mobile, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098858/jquery-mobile-form-validation-not-working-properly

Comment: Thanks for this, it's touching more on my issue. However, the problem is that I am using a javascript function for the submit button, so how would I coincide the javascript function into the jquery mobile validation?

Comment: "I am using a javascript function for the submit button" ... maybe that is not what you should do... see my answer, i hope it will help you - good luck ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `onclick="return registerUser(); return false;"` from the input button and placed it in the `submitHandler`.

To prevent the form submission i added .

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function registerUser(form) {
        var formdata = $(form).serializeArray()
        console.log(formdata);
    }

    $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
        rules: {
            txtusername: {
                required: true
            },
            txtfirstname: {
                required: true
            },
            txtlastname: {
                required: true
            },
            txtemail: {
                required: true
            },
            txtpassword: {
                required: true
            },
            passwordconfirm: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            txtusername: {
                required: "Please enter your Username."
            },
            txtfirstname: {
                required: "Please enter your First Name."
            },
            txtlastname: {
                required: "Please enter your Last Name."
            },
            txtemail: {
                required: "Please enter your Email."
            },
            txtpassword: {
                required: "Please enter your Password."
            },
            passwordconfirm: {
                required: "Please enter your password again."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
        },
        submitHandler: function (form, user) {

            registerUser(form);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js
         "></script>
<form id="form1">
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="txtusername" data-theme="d">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtusername" name="txtusername" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="txtfirstname" data-theme="d">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtfirstname" name="txtfirstname" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="txtlastname" data-theme="d">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtlastname" name="txtlastname" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="txtemail" data-theme="d">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="txtemail" name="txtemail" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Enter Email"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="txtpassword" data-theme="d">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword" data-theme="d" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
        <label for="passwordconfirm" data-theme="d">Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="text" id="passwordconfirm" name="passwordconfirm" data-theme="d" placeholder="Confirm password"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register User">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Ok so I tried the above, the form is not submitted however  the data was not submitted either when all fields were correct. Therefore, the registerUser function isn't being called? Once I click submit I recieve the alert message you have put in **alert('here you want to call: form.submit();');  " **

Comment: I have updated my code above, to show the registerUser function.

Comment: :-D hey, you have to exchange the call `alert('here you want to call: form.submit();');` with `form.submit();`. I did use the alert to demonstrate the thing...

Comment: ah ... i understand... you are using a browser database... I thought you want to send the form to a server. In my code the function registerUser is called, but it does nothing than the alert. So I think we have solved your issues ?! Have a nice weekend.

Comment: It's not the form i need submitted, the registerUser function acquires the data from the input fields of the form and then stores it in the database. However, I have put in the form.submit(); but I am not getting the success message i should be getting from the registerUser function?

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Comment: form.submit() will send the form data to the server.

Comment: I don't need this form.submit, because the registerUser function does everything I need with the data from the form (see above the registerUser function script). I put the  return registerUser(user);; in as you said however I am not getting any of the alert's I should be receiving from the registerUser function? Do you see my issue. My database is SQLite database that is stored locally on the device.

Comment: ok, i got the point... answer updated... look at your console, the formdata can be found already in an array.

Comment: Awesome stuff mate, this is now working! Although I removed all the code above the submit function (the array and document ready function) in order for the code to work. Appreciate your help, thanks!